# How do I search for an element in an array then output another element from the same array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

I have a known value from an array called `wpm` (from a function that pulls the largest value from an array of objects), that I need to then search for in an array of objects and output a value called 'raw'. So if wpm = 96, and the the array has 2 objects in it e.g.

```
[
    {raw: 36, wpm: 96},
    {raw: 45, wpm: 94}
]
```

The expected output is 36.

Comment: Is that supposed to be an array of objects?

Comment: yes, apologies - edited now

Comment: your code is wrong, array can't have named indexes in `js`, you cant declare them like that; change this: `array1 = [raw: 36, wpm: 96]` to this: `array1 = {raw: 36, wpm: 96}`

Comment: sorry, i will fix this, I made a mistake

Comment: None of your edits have produced valid data. Take a few minutes to read through how to create a [mcve]

Comment: sorry, I will make sure it all makes sense and will give that a good old read, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the function `filter` and destructuring assignment, you can get the property `raw` and to not worry about for a non-existing object.

```js
const arr = [{raw: 36, wpm: 96}, {raw: 45, wpm: 94}],
      finder = (wpmTarget) => {
        let [{raw} = {}] = arr.filter(({wpm}) => wpm === wpmTarget);
        return raw;
      };
      
console.log(finder(96));
console.log(finder(946));
```

Using the function `find` you can use the `OR` operator to assign a default empty object and avoid a `TypeError`.

```js
const arr = [{raw: 36, wpm: 96}, {raw: 45, wpm: 94}],
      finder = (wpmTarget) => {
        let {raw} = arr.find(({wpm}) => wpm === wpmTarget) || {};
        return raw;
      };
      
console.log(finder(96));
console.log(finder(946));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that is an array of objects, you can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) with destructuring.

```js
const arr = [{raw: 36, wpm: 96}, {raw: 45, wpm: 94}];
let val = 96;
let {raw} = arr.find(({wpm})=>wpm===val);
console.log(raw);
```

You can use the optional chaining operator in case the property value you are searching for might not exist.

```js
const arr = [{raw: 36, wpm: 96}, {raw: 45, wpm: 94}];
let val = 96;
console.log(arr.find(({wpm})=>wpm===val)?.raw);
val = -1;
console.log(arr.find(({wpm})=>wpm===val)?.raw);
```

Comment: @iota aren’t we not [supposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/4722345) to answer “hw questions” (how do I do “x”) with a full code solution?

Comment: @JBallin apologies if it appears that i was asking a "homework" question, but I was not, I didnt ask for code, if it was a point in the right direct e.g. saying 'use Array#find' it would be good enough for me - I will structure my questions more clearly in future.

Comment: @Proto an improvement to the question would be to show a “good faith attempt” at the problem: explain what you tried and what didn’t work.

Comment: I always forget, I have actually tried to solve my problem, this is my third hour fixing it - sorry I did not make that clear!